# new node.js express project is empty in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I am trying to open a node.js project in eclipse. I have installed the nodeclipse plugin as well as express and node.js. Now when I go and try to create a new "node.js express project" I get an empty project with the following error:

```
Node.js executable can't be found!
/Users/rajesh/Documents/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/878/0/.cp/express/bin/express /var/folders/d1/3d45qxrd2v5cr8lmt93cd1rc0000gn/T/express-work/1416463094804/CSVReader 
Unexpected Exception
```

Could any one please tell what am i missing.

I am using MAC (OSX version 10.8.5).

Comment: you should accept @Paul Verest 's answer if it helps resolving your problem .. works great for me

Answer (score 2):

Configure path to Node.js in Preferences -> Nodeclipse

Node path

See built-in help by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>

http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support

Answer (score 2):

For some reason Nodeclipse does not like having the "find node on PATH. Otherwise use Node.js instance in location below" check box checked. Under Window > Preferences > Nodeclipse uncheck it and add the path to node.exe in the text box below. This worked for me.